# how to define column range in python

Tags: python, math, numpy

I wrote a python program and I got output like this

```
ATOM         OW  HOH             6.016 23.68 63.478        
ATOM         OW  HOH             11.522 24.153 61.585   
ATOM         OW  HOH             10.849 26.167 62.012  
ATOM         OW  HOH             6.774 23.656 63.543  
ATOM         OW  HOH             8.255 22.341 66.519  
ATOM         OW  HOH             8.891 23.732 67.313  
ATOM         OW  HOH             9.193 25.411 67.03  
ATOM         OW  HOH             8.208 25.255 67.332
```

but i want output like

```
ATOM         OW  HOH              6.016 23.68  63.478        
ATOM         OW  HOH             11.522 24.153 61.585   
ATOM         OW  HOH             10.849 26.167 62.012  
ATOM         OW  HOH              6.774 23.656 63.543  
ATOM         OW  HOH              8.255 22.341 66.519  
ATOM         OW  HOH              8.891 23.732 67.313  
ATOM         OW  HOH              9.193 25.411 67.03  
ATOM         OW  HOH              8.208 25.255 67.332
```

any help is appreciable.

```
outfile2 = open('randomcoord.pdb', 'w')
hetam = 'ATOM         OW  HOH            ' + ' ' + str(round(pacord[0], 3)) + ' ' + str(round(pacord[1], 3)) + ' ' + str(round(pacord[2], 3))

            outfile2.write(hetam)

            outfile2.write('\n')
outfile2.close()
```

Comment: Do they have to have spaces between them, or are tabs ok? How about printing with `\t` ?

Comment: Paste the code you use for the printing.

Comment: @OfirIsrael: tabs aren't going to help; they'll line up columns the way the first example does, except with less flexibility in how big the gaps are.

Comment: is it possible to number each HOH, like 1, 2, 3

Comment: Note that on StackOverflow, once a question is answered, the asker is expected to [accept the most deserving answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This provides the volunteers who write answers with a symbolic reward and gives the future visitors to the site an indication of what is the best answer from the asker's point of view (the best answer as viewed by the community being determined by upvotes).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `%` formatting operator, letting it perform both the rounding and the padding:

```
with open('randomcoord.pdb', 'w') as f:
    f.write('ATOM         OW  HOH             %6.3f %6.3f %6.3f\n'
            % (pacord[0], pacord[1], pacord[2]))
```

Comment: @awanit you can change the format string to whatever you want, so if you want another space, just insert it in the format string. to add a count, just use `HOH %d` and add the counter to the tuple of arguments. see [the manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Define the length of the strings you want, let's say it's 6 (two places before the dot, three after, and the dot itself).

```
N = 6
```

Then, instead of printing as you do, write:

```
str(round(pacord[0], 3)).rjust(N,' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Like user4815162342's but with the modern formatting tools:

```
hetam = 'ATOM         OW  HOH            {:6.3f} {:6.3f} {:6.3f}\n'.format(*pacord)
```

Note that if you're writing *lines* to a file I suggest using `print`:

```
with open('randomcoord.pdb', 'w') as outfile2:
    print('ATOM         OW  HOH            {:6.3f} {:6.3f} {:6.3f}'.format(*pacord), file=outfile2)
```